# Accounts-Entry meteor Layout

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have account EntrySetup. But I want to use a diffrent layout instead of the login app layout.

I want the Signup and Login screen to only have the form.

My code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  Accounts.config({
    sendVerificationEmail: true
  });
  Accounts.ui.config({
    passwordSignupFields: 'USERNAME_AND_EMAIL'
  });
  return AccountsEntry.config({
    privacyUrl: '/privacy-policy',
    termsUrl: '/terms-of-use',
    homeRoute: '/',
    dashboardRoute: '/dashboard',
    emailToLower: true,
    profileRoute: 'profile',
    showSignupCode: false

  });
});
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until this is implemented into accounts-entry (+1 for that!) you can do it yourself like this:

```
var openRoutes = [
  "notFound",
  "entrySignIn",
  "entrySignOut",
  "entrySignUp",
  "entryForgotPassword",
  "entryResetPassword"
];

var IR_BeforeHooks = {
  openLayout: function() {
      this.router.layout("open");
  },
  requireLogin: function(pause) {
    AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this, pause);
  }
}

Router.onBeforeAction(IR_BeforeHooks.requireLogin, {except: openRoutes});
Router.onBeforeAction(IR_BeforeHooks.openLayout, {only: openRoutes});
```

So there is an `open` layout, which will be applied to all `openRoutes`.

```
<template name="layout">
  {{> yield}}
  {{> yield region="sidebar"}}
</template>

<template name="open">
  {{> yield}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

We could probably add an option to specify a layout for each route, would that help?